# Problems with loading multiple resources - log4j.properties

Tags: java, resources, log4j

So, I'm trying out the apache log4j library and I managed to get everything working correctly. I ran my program once and it did all of the logging just perfectly. Then, I went to run it again and it crashed. I tried again and again the program crashed.

I have a few .properties files in a properties/ directory. I'm using two different `.properties` files and loading them both using `getResource` and `getResourceAsStream` respectively:

first in order to configure my logger:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure(MyClass.class.getResource("properties/MyClassconfig.properties"));
```

then in order to load all of the constants used in the program:

```
properties.load(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("properties/constants.properties"));
```

As I said before, on the first run this worked perfectly. From the second run, I got this error:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file from URL [null].
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:522)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:415)
    at com.package.package2.common.main.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:69)
log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [null].
```

So, the line:

```
MyClass.class.getResource("properties/MyClassconfig.properties")
```

is no longer returning a valid URL, but instead it's returning null. I was thinking this was because some `InputStream` remained open after the first run (like the input stream opened in:

```
MyClass.class.getResource("properties/MyClassconfig.properties"); )
```

The reason I think there is a conflict between `getResource` and `getResourceAsStream` is because the crash actually happens later when I call:

```
properties.load(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("properties/constants.properties"));
```

I get:

```
Properties$LineReader.readLine() line: not available [local variables unavailable]  
Properties.load0(Properties$LineReader) line: not available 
Properties.load(InputStream) line: not available
```

Even though there is no link between the logger itself and the `Properties.load()` and its `InputStream` (other than that they are both initialized with `.properties` files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just have `log4j.properties` in your classpath and do away with all the manual resource loading?

Comment: I understand how that would work with logging, but as far as some sort of automatic resource loading for the other .properties file (the one that contains constants) I don't think that's possible. Or, if it is, how would I do that?

Comment: You have to re-tag your question and change the title. Right now it sounds like log4j specific question.

Comment: Hmm.. whenever I go to change the title or anything in the body and click Save Edits I get:
Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.
And, no matter what I change or how much I indent the code bodies and place tick marks around anything that even looks like code.. it still won't let me save the post.. gah.. this is frustrating.

Comment: Alright, after doing some inspections. I realized, much to my chagrin, that the error I was getting had absolutely nothing to do with resources or how I was doing things. It was actually because I moved my main method to another package within the project and forgot to update the path to search for the .properties files. *sigh*. But if anyone is curious, the above works perfectly for adding two different properties files to your project (given that those properties files are located in the directory you've chosen in a path from the top level - or wherever your main method is executing)